# Grant specific permissions on Google sheets

Tags: google-api, permissions, google-drive-api, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to grant specific permissions on a google spreadsheet via the Drive API.

I want all users to be set to commenters but I'd like to allow some of them to download/copy the file but not everyone. 
I've looked here https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions but I don't seem to find a way to do that. Has anyone done that before ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you check the dcoumentation which it sounds like you already have you will notice that you can set some permissions on a user

[image]

As soon as a user has access to the file any access they will be able to download it.  Google assumes that anyone that has access to see a file would also be able to download the file.